# How to perturb a Palais-Smale functional so that the Palais-Smale condition is preserved?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $J_0\colon H \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ functional on the Hilbert space $H$ satisfying the Palais-Smale condition, that is:

any sequence $u_n\in H$ such that $J_0(u_n)$ is bounded and $\mathrm{d}J_0(u_n)\stackrel{H^\star}{\to} 0$ has norm-convergent subsequences.

What conditions can we put on a perturbation functional $P$ so that $J=J_0+P$ satisfies the Palais-Smale condition?

Comment: Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @Tomás: Actually I *hope* that a linear perturbation will do. That is, $Pv=(f, v)$ for a fixed $f$, with some smallness condition on $f$. The insight for that comes from the (absolutely trivial) observation that in $\mathbb{R}$ we can linearly perturb a parabola and still have a parabola: $x^2+ax$ is a parabola. As far as I know, the easiest thing that is similar to a Palais-Smale functional is a coercive functional, and parabolas are indeed coercive.

Comment: But there is a problem with the infinite dimensional case: the level sets ($\{x\in H:\ Pv=\mbox{constant} \}$) of $P$ are not compact.